# List Processing Scala

Tags: scala

I am in the process of self teaching myself scala. 
I know java but I'm having a little problem implementing certain programs with scala.

I am reading a book specifically for learning scala and I'm trying to attempt one of the exercises for expanding my knowledge. [image]

How would you implement this in scala? 
I do have some idea on how to start it using Java. 
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
evalMono(mono: (Double, Double), x:Double) = mono._1 * Math.pow(x, mono._2)

evalPoly(poly: List[(Double, Double), x:Double) = poly.map (item => evalMono(item, x)).sum
```